# Is ASP.NET OnClick attribute JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

For example:

```
<asp:Button id="Button1"
               Text="Click here for greeting..."
               OnClick="GreetingBtn_Click" 
               runat="server"/>
```

so my questions is:

1. Is OnClick a javascript event on client side? if yes, does it mean that asp.net will add javascript code to the page then send the page back to browser?
2. Sine javascript is case sensitivity, so "OnClick" should be "onclick"?

Comment: The *attribute* is HTML; the attribute *value* is JavaScript.

Comment: Why don't you take a look at the generated html. It answers your questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you look [there](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclick) you'll see that this event will be executed on the server side. But ASP.NET will also generate code on client side something like this:

```
onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(...
```

so click on the button will produces postback to the server

Comment: I think the event is handled on server side, not sure if this is what u mean. So why is OnClick rather than Onclick

Comment: It's ASP.NET Webforms. They works like this. ASP.NET creates html button with it's own onclick js code which I've shown in the answer to create request to the server, the code you place in the GreetingBtn_Click is the code executing on the server side written on c#, VB etc... If you want to create just html button with logic on the client, use just button, not asp:Button. OnClick written with that case to emphasize that it is not client code executing on JS. Is it clear now?